# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debug_toolbar'

Tags: python-3.6, django-1.11, django-debug-toolbar

In trying to make the migrations with `python manage.py runserver`, I got the following traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/infinity/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/infinity/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/infinity/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/infinity/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/infinity/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/home/infinity/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debug_toolbar'
```

Here is a part of the setting file

```
from .common import *  # noqa

DEV = True
DEBUG = True
STAGE = 'dev'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

USERENA_USE_HTTPS = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost']

INSTALLED_APPS = INSTALLED_APPS + [
    'debug_toolbar',
    'django_extensions',
]

MIDDLEWARE = MIDDLEWARE + [
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
]

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = [
    'debug_toolbar.panels.versions.VersionsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.settings.SettingsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeadersPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.request.RequestPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.staticfiles.StaticFilesPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.templates.TemplatesPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.cache.CachePanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.logging.LoggingPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.redirects.RedirectsPanel',
]

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': False,
}
```

I can't explain why this app is never loaded. I am struggling with this problem for a good while now. Could anyone have some time to help me with that?

Comment: Did you import the module in `urls`?

Answer (score 1):

try this one: `pip install django-debug-toolbar`

Answer (score 0):

Use below command :

python -m pip install -e git+https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar.git#egg=django-debug-toolbar

$ python -m pip install -e git+https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar.git#egg=django-debug-toolbar